# Why does our about page not include a real Christianity question?

Tags: discussion, tour

If you look at our **[about](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/about)** page, you will see an example question about **unicorns** (which is a [frequently used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicorn) [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) / [joke](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow) on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)).

However, if you look at eg [Sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) you will see that its **[about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about)** page contains a real example question for its site.

Why is that?

At first glance, it might not seem like a big deal. But a first time user (the target audience for the about page) would be forgiven for thinking this is a joke site.

Comment: Many other sites do have their own questions (eg [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/about)) though apparently Christianity is not the only one (eg [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about)).

Comment: I thought we brought this up before and there was some lame reason. Maybe we can change it now.

Comment: @fredsbend: [You're right!](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/odd-question-selection-in-the-about-section-of-the-site) - looks like mine is a duplicate.

Comment: IDK, turn this into a poll asking for the question to be a real question from the site. I strongly disagree with Caleb on the other post. I would very much rather have "hereseys" than unicorns.

Comment: @fredsbend maybe a better use would be to conjure a question/answer set that we could collaborate on that fulfill the requirements and show the mechanics that are desirable.

Comment: @waxeagle My understanding is that there needs to be at least two answers and one selected and neither the answers nor the question can exceed a certain length. If that is so, there may be single answer questions on the site and simply added a second answer would put it in the requirements.

Comment: @fredsbend keep your eyes pealed and if you see one let us know :)

Comment: I think we need to create one...